# Spring-Контроллер не обрабатывает запросы

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven, tomcat

Пытаюсь освоить Spring MVC и для этого создал просто приложение, которое при заходе на `localhost:8080` должно выдавать простую JSP-страничку с двумя надписями "TEST"

Но оно не работает! Не знаю, что именно не так, но вместо нужной странички апач показывает это:

[image: Ошибка 404]

Файловая структура проекта выглядит так:

[image: Файловая структура проекта]

Содержимое файла `pom.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mvc-beginning-b-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>


</project>
```

Содержимое файла `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Содержимое файла `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.max" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Код класса `HomeController` выглядит так:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showMyPage(){
        return "main-menu";
    }

}
```

Apache Tomcat сконфигурирован следующим образом:

[image: Apache Tomcat config]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема и как мне её решить?
(Я всё делал по этому руководству: [2016-Create a web app with Intellij Ultimate Edition 15 - Spring MVC - Tomcat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6l4pqhd4WI&list=LLnfrmW83oPvUDmQZ2rw2uJg&index=2&t=2s))

Comment: Второй скрин, поле `Application context` поменяй на `/`

Comment: а томкат установлен в систему или это встроенный в идее?

Comment: Установленный в систему

Comment: @FirstSin, спасибо огромное! Теперь вроде всё работает!  Оформишь свой коммент в качестве ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражаю огромную благодарность участнику [FirstSin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/338621/first-sin), который решил мою проблему.

Решение заключается в следующем: при конфигурации `Tomcat` в разделе `Deployment` нужно пролистать вниз и отредактировать поле `Apllication context`, указав в нём значение `\`.

Иначе, запросы будут идти по другому пути (например, если указать в `Apllication context` значение `\wrong_route`, то контроллер, настроенный на путь `\page`, будет ждать запрос по адресу `localhost:8080\wrong_route\page`, а не `localhost:8080\page`)